# Create a Spotify Group session using Spotify API

Tags: api, spotify

Spotify has added the group session not that long ago and I am interested in using this feature in my application.

I went through their API guide but cannot find any endpoint for the creation of a group session and for letting my users join one automatically without the need to have a link sent to them to join.

Any idea where I can find any relevant information on the topic?